# find doesn't search within subdirectories

Tags: macos, unix

I'm using `find . -name '*~'` to find files that end with `~` but it only shows files that are not in the subdirectories. When I use `find . -name "#*"` it shows all files including the ones that are in the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

If the subdirectory is a symbolic link, `find` will not follow it by default. Try:

```
find -L . -name '*~'
```

See [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) for more.